I just opened my account. deposited solana and it I suddenly dont see it anymore?
I really need help on this does anyone have any contact I needed to at least get live chat but its AI and its very useless. email needs time...

To check if the transfer of SOL went to your Phantom wallet correctly, you can check Solana Explorer
Just enter your Sending or Receiving Address
